# Conexión dinámica en crystal report c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

hola quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que pueda generar los reportes desde distintas instancias de SQL, tengo que usar datasets? o que otra forma tengo? actualmente tengo implementado los procedimientos almacenados que se ejecutan automáticamente con el reporte pero al cambiar de conexión SQL da error.

El problema está cuando quiero probar el reporte en otra PC, como la instancia SQL no es la misma entonces da error de conexión, hay alguna forma de hacerlo de manera genérica?? (La configuración del origen de datos lo hice a través del menú del crystal)

saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes conectarlo a un dataset tipado, en donde defines la estructura de los datos, pero sin una db

[Working On RDLC Report In C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2f59d0/working-on-rdlc-report-in-Asp-Net/)

mas alla que en el articulo es un aspx, valida como sea un xsd donde define el datatable y lo conecta al reporte `rdlc`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o sea es un reporte local conectado a un `dataset tipado`